# Intranet services that allow Google Groups for permissioning?

Tags: permissions, openid, intranet, google-openid, google-groups

My environment is heavily invested in Google Apps. We're building a new intranet and not impressed with Google Sites. I'd like to recommend another intranet service, but if it doesn't allow Google's Open ID and permissioning via Google Groups, I'll never get any traction. Has anyone had good luck with Google Apps + a separate intranet service?